# How to find indexPath for tapped accessory button in tableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, segue

I've simple `UITableView` with one section and few rows. When user clicks cell accessory button (which is connected with `detailsSegue`. I want to know what cell row was it. So than I can select right object from my array and assign it to the variable from the next view.

I have used delegate method `tableview:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` and assigned indexPath value to my private property `myRow`. Than in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method I used my `self.myRow.row` value to select right object from array.

My problem is that these two methods seems to execute in wrong order. From the NSLog I can see that `prepareForSegue:sender:` method is executed first and my delegate method is changing value of `self.myRow` after it.

So `prepareForSegue:sender:` method is always passing wrong object to the next view (the one that was tapped previously).

Sorry for my english guys. Thanks for help in advance.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.myRow = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"tapped button at row: %i",self.myRow.row); 
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addSegue"]) {
        AddViewController *avc = segue.destinationViewController;
        avc.delegate = self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailsSegue"]) {
        NSLog(@"Segue row: %i",self.myRow.row);
        Annotation *annotation = [self.viewsList objectAtIndex:self.myRow.row];
        NSLog(@"Segue annotation object: %@",annotation.title);
        DetailsViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.wikiKey = annotation.title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As you have discovered, the system sends you the `prepareForSegue:sender:` message *before* it sends you the `tableview:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` message.

**But**, when it sends you the `prepareForSegue:sender:` message, the `sender` argument is the `UITableViewCell` containing the accessory view.  You can use that to determine which row's accessory button was tapped:

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailsSegue"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Annotation *annotation = [self.viewsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailsViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    dvc.wikiKey = annotation.title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The sender will be the accessory button, right? In that case you should be able to find its containing cell by going up through super views and then get the index path of that cell. I’ve used a method like this before to do the first part:

```
+ (UITableViewCell *)findParentCellOfView:(UIView *)view {
  if (view == nil || [view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    return (UITableViewCell *)view;
  }
  return [self findParentCellOfView:[view superview]];
}
```

Comment: The sender is actually the cell, not the accessory button.

Answer (score 2):

// I tell you a simple and a better and an easy option :-

// Solution :- You can assign tag to button of accessory view in this method of tableView

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // set accessory view
    UIButton *oValidHomeAccessryBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // set target of accessory view button
    [oValidHomeAccessryBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(AccessoryAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // set tag of accessory view button to the row of table
    oValidHomeAccessryBtn.tag =indexPath.row;

    // set button to accessory view
    cell.accessoryView = oValidHomeAccessryBtn ;
}
```

// Make the method you passed in selector and get tag value and you would get indexPath of accessory view clicked

```
- (void)AccessoryAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[sender tag]);
}
```

This is the simplest way to get the indexPat of row in which you clicked the accessory view.

Answer (score -3):

What you need to do is call the `segue` programmatically from the delegate method.  Assuming you're using storyboards, you'll need to unlink the `segue` in the storyboard and in your delegate method use:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"IdentifierNameHere" sender: self];
```